# mq_send : bad file descriptor

Tags: arm

I have tried executing sample message queue programs on arm (linux) platform and mq_send() throws error number 9  (Bad file descriptor).
1) mq is enabled in kernel i.e CONFIG_POSIX_MQUEUE and CONFIG_POSIX_MQUEUE_SYSCTL
2) using -lrt to compile the programs
Kindly let me know how to resolve this.